# Need help figuring out why this wont work

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Why do I get a syntax error on the first print line whenever I try to run this?

```
def dice():
    import random
    diceAmount = input('How many dice (Up to 5)')
    diceNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    if diceAmount > 1:
       die = "die"
    else:
    die = "dice"
    diceTotal = (math.factorial(6)/((math.factorial(6-
    random.choice(diceNumbers))*math.factorial(random.choice(diceNumbers)))

    print("You chose " +diceAmount + die)
    print(diceTotal*diceAmount)
dice()
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: Check your parentheses, and strongly consider reorganizing your code to need less of them.

Comment: The line after `else:` must be indented.

Comment: What syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed code

```
def dice():
    import random
    import math
    diceAmount = input('How many dice (Up to 5)')
    diceNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    if diceAmount > 1:
        die = "die"
    else:
        die = "dice"
    diceTotal = math.factorial(6)/math.factorial(6-random.choice(diceNumbers))*math.factorial(random.choice(diceNumbers))

    print "You chose " +diceAmount + die
    print diceTotal*diceAmount
dice()
```